# Kotlin Compose Function Screen renders differently for same structure code

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, rendering

I have two Composable functions that have practically the same structure code but they render differently in the Android Studio simulator.

I am using:

sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"

kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'

implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')

androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')

First Screen Code:

```
@Composable
fun BuildScreenHouse(viewModel: InventoryViewModel, navController: NavHostController, houseId: String?, name: String?, use: String?, location: String?)  {

val house = houseId!!.toLong()

ScreenLandscape()

Column {


    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        //.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)

    ) {

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {


            Text(
                text = "Nick Name", fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.50f),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold

            )

            Text(
                text = "Use", fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.50f),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold

            )
        }

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

            Text(
                text = name!!, fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.50f),
                color = Color.Black

            )

            Text(
                text = use!!, fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.50f),
                color = Color.Black

            )
        }


        Button(
            onClick = { navController.navigate("InsertScreenFloor/${houseId}/${URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8")}") },
            //Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

        ) {
            Text(text = "Insert Floor into House")
        }
    }

    Column(
        //horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        //.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)

    ) {
        // The House List
        FloorsList(viewModel = viewModel, navController, house, location!!)

    }
}
```

}

Rendered image:

[image]

Second Screen Code:

```
@Composable
fun BuildScreenFloor(viewModel: InventoryViewModel, navController: NavHostController, floorId: String?, floorname: String?, location: String?) {

val floor = floorId!!.toLong()

ScreenLandscape()

Column {

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        //.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)


    ) {


        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

            Text(
                text = "Floor Name", fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold

            )

        }

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

            Text(
                text = floorname!!, fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.Black

            )
        }
    }

    Button(
        onClick = { navController.navigate("InsertScreenRoom/${floorId}/${URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8")}") },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

    ) {
        Text(text = "Insert Room into Floor")
    }

    Column(
        //horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        //.verticalScroll(state = scrollState)

    ) {

        // The House List
        RoomsList(viewModel = viewModel, navController, floor, location!!)

    }
}
```

}

Rendered image:

[image]

I do not see why the first segment in the second screen renders left instead of Center.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error with the location of the Button but did not found why the Text is not responding the same (Alignment.CenterHorizontally). But I found a work around to make them respond in a satisfactory way.

The Button was outside the scope of the Column with the correct format.

For the Text I added a TextAlign property.

This are the code changes:

```
) {


        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            //horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.Center,
            //modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {

            Text(
                text = "Floor Name", fontSize = 20.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center, //Added property
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold

            )

        }

        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {

            Text(
                text = floorname!!, fontSize = 20.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center, //Added property
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.Black

            )
        }

        Button(
            onClick = { navController.navigate("InsertScreenRoom/${floorId}/${URLEncoder.encode(location, "utf-8")}") },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

        ) {
            Text(text = "Insert Room into Floor")
        }
    }
```